# How long for a spinning cylinder in space to stop spinning?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, friction, drag, estimation

Suppose we spin a solid cylinder of inertia $J$ and mass $m$ to a speed of $n$ rpm. Assuming it is in close earth orbit, about the same distance as ISS, how long would it take to lose all its angular momentum (due to friction with the thin atmosphere)?

Comment: The few particles that are in space, some ppm. I imagine it cannot spin indefinitely.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert There should still be a positive mass density al be it small.

Comment: Gotcha.  [This report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19710016459/downloads/19710016459.pdf) seems to have some useful information;  hopefully I'll have time to read it over more carefully soon and provide a fuller response.  You might also consider asking this question on [Space.SE];  some bona fide NASA experts hang out over there.

Comment: FWIW, "Atmospheric drag reduces the [ISS] altitude by about 2 km a month on average". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks!